# selector subscription is not being called

Tags: ngxs

Can someone explain when exactly is `selector` subscription is called? My previous understanding was whenever reducer changes the `state` (some diff is created), `selector` is called. But in following code, it's not happening.

Following selector (line A) is not being called when I dispatch the `SaveVersionSuccess`. In reducer I change `state.version.versions[0].updated_fields.workflow` from `true` to `false`.

Can someone explain why? [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/goodmite/ngxs-selector-not-working)

```
@Select(state => state.version.versions) version$: Observable<any[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.version$.subscribe((versions) => {//line A
      alert()
    });
  }


  test(){
    this.store.dispatch([
      new SaveVersionSuccess({bot:null, version:{id: 1, updated_fields:{'workflow':false}}})
    ]);
```

**Reducer**

```
  @Action(SaveVersionSuccess)
  SaveVersionSuccess({patchState, setState, getState, dispatch,}: StateContext<ICodeInputState>, {payload}: SaveVersionSuccess) {
    let state = getState();
    let index = state.versions.findIndex((version) => version.id === payload.version.id);
    let index_pristine = state.versions_pristine.findIndex((version) => version.id === payload.version.id);

    state.versions[index] = {
      ...payload.version
    };
    state.versions_pristine[index_pristine] = {
      ...payload.version
    };
    patchState({...state});
}
```

**Initial state**

```
const codeInputState: ICodeInputState = {
  versions: [{id: 1, updated_fields:{'workflow':true}}],
  versions_pristine: [{id: 1, updated_fields:{'workflow':true}}]
};
```

Comment: I tend to not use as much destructing, but it may be patchState(state); You could use the DevTools plugin and check the state before/after you call test(). BTW, what calls test()?

Comment: Hey, `patchState(state)` doesnt help either. devtools show the diff when test is called for the first time as expected. test() is called by a button in component template. I have attached a stackblitz link, you can check if you are on laptop. Thanks.

Comment: try to set the developmentMode in your store forRoot initialization, so that you can  freeze your store using deep-freeze-strict module.and look if its a problem of mutation

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggested it looks like an issue with immutability when patching the state, the original is modifying the existing state rather than patching new state.

I tried this version on your StackBlitz, seemed to work as I think you want it to:

```
@Action(SaveVersionSuccess)
  SaveVersionSuccess({patchState, setState, getState, dispatch,}: StateContext<ICodeInputState>, {payload}: SaveVersionSuccess) {
    let state = getState();
    let index = state.versions.findIndex((version) => version.id === payload.version.id);
    let index_pristine = state.versions_pristine.findIndex((version) => version.id === payload.version.id);

    // Create a new versions array
    const versions = [...state.versions];
    // Patch the value at the required index
    versions[index] = payload.version;

    // Create a new versions_pristine array
    const versions_pristine = [...state.versions_pristine];
    // Patch the value at the required index
    versions_pristine[index_pristine] = payload.version;

    // Patch the state with the new arrays    
    patchState({
      versions: versions,
      versions_pristine: versions_pristine
    });
  }
```